# Updating more than one attribute at one time in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have a page where a user can see a list of messages in a current threaded conversation.

**They can delete each message using a delete link (a link inside an each loop for each message):**

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', message, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => message.body %> <br />
```

**This basically connects them to an action in my messages_controller:**

```
  def destroy

  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @message.update_attribute('sender_status', 1) if @message.sender_id == current_user.id
  @message.update_attribute('recipient_status', 1) if @message.recipient_id == current_user.id
  @message.destroy if @message.sender_status == 1 && @message.recipient_status == 1

  flash[:success] = "Message deleted"
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

What I'd like to have now is one link before all the messages (so I won't put this in the each block). This link will be called "delete all" and rather than updating 1 attribute with the value 1 it will update all the attributes (sender/recipient_status) to 1 so that a user doesn't have to click on each individual messages delete link.

I'm a bit stuck with how to do this. I don't use checkboxes but rather delete links so for the delete all I'd rather use a link too.

Can any body offer me a solution with an example please? I'd really appreciate it. Thought I'd sleep on it last night and have an idea in the morning but still nothing comes to mind.

Kind regards

**Update**

The messages belong to a conversation. I can either grab a conversation by:
1) The MessageThread table. This stores the message_id of the first message in the conversation which is the parent_id of the other messages in that conversation. So for example.

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| id  | sende... | reci... | body    | pare... | status | crea... | updat... | sende... | recip... |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 220 | 4        | 1       | hi      | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 221 | 1        | 4       | hey     | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 222 | 4        | 1       | hi      | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 223 | 1        | 4       | hi      | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 232 | 1        | 4       | good    | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 233 | 4        | 1       | and ... | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 237 | 1        | 4       | hmm     | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 238 | 1        | 4       | yay     | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
| 239 | 1        | 4       | yess    | 220     | 0      | 2012... | 2012-... | 0        | 0        |
```

2) I can also just find the conversation by parent id. e.g. m = Message.find_by_parent_id(220).

to get the other messages in the convo I would just type m.children

Here is how my messagethreads table looks:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | message_id | sender_id | recipient_id | status | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 102 | 247        | 1         | 5            | 0      | 2012-02-16 16:18... | 2012-02-16 16:18... |
| 101 | 246        | 1         | 3            | 0      | 2012-02-16 16:14... | 2012-02-16 16:14... |
| 90  | 220        | 4         | 1            | 0      | 2012-02-15 14:05... | 2012-02-15 14:05... |
| 89  | 219        | 4         | 38           | 0      | 2012-02-15 12:26... | 2012-02-15 12:26... |
| 88  | 218        | 2         | 4            | 0      | 2012-02-14 13:41... | 2012-02-14 13:41... |
| 87  | 210        | 1         | 2            | 0      | 2012-02-14 13:31... | 2012-02-14 13:31... |
+-----+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is what is working for me:

```
 def destroy_all_messages

  Message.find_by_parent_id(params[:format]).children.each do |message|
    message.update_attribute('sender_status', 1) if message.sender_id == current_user.id
    message.update_attribute('recipient_status', 1) if message.recipient_id == current_user.id
    message.destroy if message.sender_status == 1 && message.recipient_status == 1
  end
        flash[:success] = "Messages deleted"
    redirect_to :back
end
```

and:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete All', messages_delete_all_messages_path(@current_thread.message_id), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %> <br />
```

This is what's working for me.. Opinions?
I noticed I had to use "params[:format]" to grab the params I passed into the link_to message path in my controller.

Comment: I guess there should be an entity that is related to current conversation thread, for example a `conversation` record. If so pass the conversation record id, find out all messages of that conversation to delete.

Comment: Added some more info to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are those messages grouped? Do they belong to a Conversation?

If it's a Conversation (with has_many :messages) You could add a "delete all messages" button to the conversation that sends the id of this conversation to a delete_messages action. In this action do

```
def destroy_messages

  Conversation.find(params[:id]).messages.each do |message|
    message.update_attribute('sender_status', 1) if message.sender_id == current_user.id
    message.update_attribute('recipient_status', 1) if message.recipient_id == current_user.id
    message.destroy if message.sender_status == 1 && message.recipient_status == 1
  end
end
```

Could need some details for proper authorization. If there is no Conversation model, do something similar after searching for the messages to delete. (Or tell us some details what exactly you display and how you decide to display it)

**Update**

This should be just the same. If you can get all messages that easy, just replace "Conversation" with the parent message. You link should send the id of the parent message and then run through all of it's child messages and update their status. Should be easy enough.

```
m = Message.find(params[:id])
m.children.each do |message|
    ... as above ...
end
```

In general, just send an identifier (id of parent in this case) that is good enough to identify the messages to be deleted, use it to run a find and then update the records.

Comment: Hi added some info to my post. There are 2 ways I can grab the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'update_attributes' method instead and pass the fields that you want to update as a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Thorsten is spot on.

May I suggest an additional clean up?

Message.rb

```
def is_deletable?(current_user)
   if (self.sender_status == 1 || self.sender_id == current_user.id) &&
       (self.recipient_status == 1 || self.recipient_id == current_user.id)
     true
   else
     false
   end
end
```

message_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  if @message.is_deletable?(current_user)
   @message.destroy 
   flash[:success] = "Message deleted"
  else
   flash[:error] = "You dont have permission to delete this message"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end

def destroy_messages

 Message.find_by_parent_id(params[:id]).each do |message|
  message.destroy if message.is_deletable?(current_user)
 end
 flash[:success] = "Deleted all permissible messages"
 redirect_to :back
end
```

This has the added benefit of adding an additional update statement to a row you're just about to delete, so should make things faster & more efficient.

Comment: This is a good clean up. I was just getting things working then eventually going to go over my whole project and clean up the code.. taking things out of the controller that could actually be in the model. Your example looks really good.